# Concept of Facets in the structure of reductive algebraic groups

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Where can I find a precise definition of Facet ? In some online notes it is stated that Facet is a maximal subset of co-characters having the same sign for every root. But shouldn't then every facet is a Weyl chamber?

Comment: On the apartment $A$  attached to some maximal split torus $T$ of your reductive $k$-group $G$, the roots of $T$ may be viewed as linear functionnal on $A$. You have an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $A$ given by $x\sim y$ iff $sgn (\alpha (x)) =sgn (\alpha (y))$ for all roots $\alpha$. The equivalence classes are called facets. Weyl chambers are facets of maximal dimension, i.e. of dimension the split rank of $G$ minus $1$. But in general there are facets of smaller dimension.

Comment: I don't know what online notes you are quoting, but it's most important to state what type of "Weyl group" you are using.    In the geometry of a finite (or affine) Weyl group, there are "facets" of various dimensions obtained by starting with walls of Weyl chambers (or alcoves) and then intersecting some of these.    Bourbaki's *Groupes et algebres de Lie* Chapter IV-VI contains a lot of information, while Jantzen's book *Representations of Algebraic Groups* is especially detailed for affine Weyl groups.    Anyway, "facet" has a geometric origin, but gets adapted to related structures.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am looking at a reductive algebraic group over an algebraically closed field , and the Weyl group $W(G,T)$ w.r..t a fixed maximal torus in $G$ which is a finite group.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's helpful to expand on the comment made by Paul Broussous.
There may be some differences in the way "facets" are explained in the literature, but from any viewpoint these are *not* the same as Weyl chambers.   Instead, the Weyl chambers are the facets of maximal dimension (equal to the semisimple rank $n$ of the reductive group involved).   Starting with the root system and a corresponding system of reflecting hyperplanes (one for each pair of roots $\pm \alpha$), the Weyl chambers are the connected components of the complement of the union of hyperplanes in the ambient euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$.    But other facets occur in their closures, starting with the *walls* of each Weyl chamber (of codimension one in the closure of that chamber).   Eventually each closure of a Weyl chamber is a disjoint union of facets of different dimension, the extreme case being a point.

This is the kind of description one finds in Bourbaki *Lie Groups and Lie Algebras*, Chap. 4-6 (especially section 5.1) or Jantzen *Representations of Algebraic Groups* (II.6).    The formal definition of "facet" is given just in terms of the root system.  Naturally it's also possible to recast definitions in terms of the coroots, depending on how the geometric ideas are being approached.   I guess this is where your reference to cocharacters comes into play.

Comment: In polyhedral combinatorics the accepted terminology is that a "facet" is a "face" of maximal dimension. It seems quite strange to use facet to mean flats of different dimension.

Comment: @Sam: This may cause some confusion, but it's not my idea.   It apparently originated in work of Tits on buildings, then was taken over by Bourbaki and others in the context of root systems and Weyl groups.   (Conflicting uses of terminology are probably inevitable in mathematics, such as the term "block".)